# Set the style of a cell

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, cells, style

I know it's possible to programmatically change options on the selection in a notebook.
I'd like to create a button that lets me change the style of a cell.  It's a style that doesn't have a keyboard shortcut,   `"ItemParagraph"`

Something like

```
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[SelectedNotebook[]], CellStyle->"ItemParagraph"]
```

but `CellStyle` is for `NotebookFind`.   Is there some way to do this?  I just couldn't find the cell option I needed.  I checked the `Options` for `Cell` but there are hundreds and I couldn't see anything that looked right...

Comment: Yes,  I have a palette open onscreen so a button on that palette would be much faster than going through the Format -->   Style  -->  Item Paragraph menu.

Comment: Maybe useful : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9956/363

Comment: I believe that post shows how to set the default for NEW cells... I am wondering how to select a cell and change whatever option would be to "ItemParagraph"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this button may help you:

```
Button["ItemParagraph", FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "Style", "ItemParagraph"]]
```

The whole cell may be selected with:

```
SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, Cell]
```

Comment: Thank you so much,  exactly what I was looking for,  does just what I need, and helps me to see ways to use that for other things.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if any of them can be callled documented but I know three ways to do this:

mentioned above:

#### `FrontEndToken` way:

```
(
 SelectionMove[#, All, Cell]; 
 FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "Style", "Title"]
) & /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]
```

or

#### `SelectionSetStyle` way:

```
(
 SelectionMove[#, All, Cell];
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionSetStyle[#, "Title"]]
   ) & /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]
```

or (*which is implemented with code from above*)

#### `CellStyleNames` way:

```
(
 SelectionMove[#, All, Cell];
 Experimental`CellStyleNames[#] = "Title";
) & /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]
```

Comment: Using `Scan[]` along with your suggestion seems to work faster than `SelectionMove[]` (at least for me).  Not sure why.   Try Scan[(Experimental`CellStyleNames[#] = "Title") &, 
 Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]]

Comment: This is significantly faster.... `Scan[(SetOptions[#, "Title"]) &, Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]]` But it doesn't delete the old style.  It appends the new one.  Still works though.  You can see the double styles if you press Shift+Command+E in any title cell.  Do you think there is a way to fix the code to address this?  Seems like using `SetOptions[]` is quite a bit faster, but need to fix the double style created.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Yep, that was the problem with SetOptions. I don't know how to fix it :/

Answer (score 2):

A function showing a different way to modify the style of a cell:

```
ChangeStyle[cell_CellObject, style_String] := 
  NotebookWrite[cell, ReplacePart[NotebookRead[cell], 2 -> style]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution below was found in the documentation under Cells->Applications.  It appends the new style to the old one, which isn't optimal and creates a mess in most cases.  I'll leave it here for reference.  Kuba noted that `Cells[]` allow for more than one style and there may not be a mechanism yet for manipulating these styles easily using `SetOptions[]` or `CurrentValue[]`

```
Scan[(CurrentValue[#, StyleNames] = "Title") &, 
 Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"]]
```

You can also try this brute force approach below which reads the whole notebook.  It is fast.  But definitely not as straight forward as Kuba's solutions above.

```
NotebookPut[ NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]] /. Cell[x_, "Section", y__] -> Cell[x, "Title", y], InputNotebook[]];
```

Comment: Where in documentation? :), p.s. it adds a style instead of replacing it.

Comment: In Cells structure tutorial multiple styles cell syntax is documented so I'd call it a mess in tool we have to deal with this. Since we can have multiple styles one may need to: replace all with one, change the latest, replace a specific one, etc etc. Tools are not there or are obscure.

Comment: You are reading whole notebook which sees like an overkill for most cases. May be good though if you need to change a lot at once.