# Syntax for FrontEnd`SelectionSetStyle

Tags: front-end, syntax, undocumented

I know `` FrontEnd`SelectionSetStyle `` is undocumented, but its name suggests it does what I need. What is its syntax?

I have already tried several variations of the following button on some selected code in an input cell.

```
Button["set", 
  FrontEnd`SelectionSetStyle[FontColor, RGBColor[{1, 0, 0}]];
  Print[CurrentValue["SelectionData"]]]
```

---

**Update**

Using the kernel, the following code does what I need:

```
Button["set", 
 SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], FontColor -> RGBColor[{0, .7, .5}]]; 
 Print[CurrentValue["SelectionData"]]]
```

I assume that `` FrontEnd`SelectionSetStyle `` can change the font color of the selection while using the front end only. If so, what is its syntax?

Comment: After your update it is unclear what your question is. Can "what" be done in the front end only?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: I re-worded the question, thank you for the note.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumptions are most probably wrong, it seems that this function is meant to change `CellStyle`.

e.g. use this code to convert Input cells to Title cells in current notebook:

```
(
 SelectionMove[#, All, Cell];
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionSetStyle[#, "Title"]]
   ) & /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]
```

Used here: [Set the style of a cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78774/5478) (*link corrected*)

Found there: [How can I get the style of a CellObject?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78771/5478)