# How can I get the style of a CellObject?

Tags: notebooks, cells

I want to work on a notebook programmatically with CellObjects.

lets create a notebook for example:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{TextCell["a", "Title"], Cell["b", "Subtitle"], 
 Cell["c", "Text"]}];
```

this gives the CellObjects of the notebook:

```
cells = Cells[nb]
```

Now i want to have a function like:

```
 getCellStyle/@cells
```

Out:

```
 {"Title", "Subtitle", "Text"}
```

I know that i could work with selections as suggested in this question: [How can I get the style of selected cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21915/how-can-i-get-the-style-of-selected-cells)

But its more practical in my case to work directly with the `CellObjects`. I think there must be a way to get the style, since the `CellObjects` look in the FrontEnd like `CellObject["style"]`

I just want to extract that `"style"`.

Comment: related: [32957](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32957/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something more documented:

```
NotebookRead[ PreviousCell[] ][[2]]
```

> ```
> "Section"
> ```

---

It seems there is something exactly what you need, quite not ready probably since in `` Experimental` `` context:

```
Experimental`CellStyleNames[ PreviousCell[] ]
```

> ```
> "Output"
> ```

and `` Experimental`CellStyleNames[] `` gives you styles of all cells in notebook!, quite useful sometimes. Keep in mind that it is undocumented.

p.s. closer look reveals that it is nothing more than `CellInformation` approach:

```
ClearAttributes[Experimental`CellStyleNames, ReadProtected];

Block[{$ContextPath},

 AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Experimental`"];

 AppendTo[$ContextPath, "NotebookTools`UtilitiesDump`"];

 ?? Experimental`CellStyleNames
 ]
```

[image]

take a closer look at the very first definition, now you have **[new way to set cell style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78774/5478):**

```
(Experimental`CellStyleNames[#] = "Title") & @ PreviousCell[]
```

---

Comment: Nice discovery. To clarify: ``Experimental```CellStyleNames@Cells[nb] works, i.e., directly on the CellObjects. So getCellStyles = Experimental`CellStyleNames

Comment: not exactly ...

Comment: @RolfMertig Agree, but `PreviousCell` is a cell object.

Comment: sure. How do I escape a quote in comments?

Comment: @RolfMertig You have to wrap with one more that you want to display inside, and if here is one at the end you have to add whitespace.

Comment: thank you Kuba, this answered two of my questions! But its funny that `Experimental-CellStyleNames` does internally exactly the same thing, that i was doing as my workaround before ^^
Before i was using `("Style" /. Developer-CellInformation[#] & )` to get the CellStyle, but i was thinking that its a very slow way to find out the CellStyle, because CellInformation gives you much more Information than needed in this case.
The boxes-method by kguler is in fact faster: I improved it a little bit:
`getCellStyle[cell_CellObject] := 
 If[StringQ[#], #, $Failed] &@ToExpression[ToBoxes[cell]〚1, -1〛]`

Comment: @sacratus great I could help, Thanks for info about performance. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
Last /@ FilterRules[Developer`CellInformation[nb], "Style"]
(* {"Title", "Subtitle", "Text"} *)
```

Or

```
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]; "Style" /.  Developer`CellInformation[nb]
(* {"Title", "Subtitle", "Text"} *)
```

Working with `CellObjects`:

```
RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#][[1, -1]]] & /@ Cells[nb]
(* {"Title", "Subtitle", "Text"}  *)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, it works for the most cases, but you did not used the `CellObjects`. I specify my question, why i need to work with `CellObjects`...

Comment: @sacratus, just added a method that works with `CellObject`s. Not sure how robust it is though.

Comment: Nice this is what i wanted, but instead of `RawBoxes` one should use `ToExpression` so that the function returns a String instead of RawBoxes. Thank You!

Comment: @sacratus it works with cell objects: ``"Style" /. Developer`CellInformation@PreviousCell[]``

Comment: The last one is RawBoxes["\"Input\""] for example. So it looks ok but it isn't.