# Programatically align text in the Front End

Tags: front-end

One can select a cell and using the Front End menu perform

*Format -> Text Alignment -> Align at 25%*

Other options are given as well.

I have learned from Stack Exchange how to create a button and modify some text. For example I can select some text and click the button created by this code

```
CreatePalette[
 Button["Highlight",
  FrontEndTokenExecute["FontFamily", "Arial"];
  FrontEndTokenExecute["FontColor", Blue];
  FrontEndTokenExecute["FontSlant", "Italic"];
  FrontEndTokenExecute["FontWeight", "Bold"];
  ],
 WindowTitle -> "Highligh Text"
 ]
```

in order to change its font to blue and face to italic.

I would like to do the same thing except aligning a cell. I would also like the ability to control the alignment percentage.

I have searched the Mathematica Stack Exchange and can't find a similar question.

When I look at all the possibilities as described in [What is the complete list of valid Front End Tokens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-front-end-tokens) I come across some alignment properties (e.g., AlignCentersHorizontally) but they do not work on a cell.

Anybody have a clue as to how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of how to set the cell option ***Styles*** can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42237/palette-to-set-cell-options-such-as-background-editable-and-initialization-prope).

The question is what is the token used to set the cell alignment?

To answer this create some five cells and then manually set the cell alignment to *Align Left, Align at 25%, Align Center, Align at 75%* and *Align Right* using the Format menu and Text Alignment row.

Now select a cell and go to Option Inspector... -> Formatting Options -> Text Layout Options.

In that group one Option is ***TextAlignment***.

Studying the values for the example cases shows:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is clear from this data that Left alignment corresponds to -1 and Right alignment to +1. Linear interpolation gives the rest of the results (e.g., Align at 25% corresponds to -0.5).

Thus to create a palette with buttons to align the text one could use:

```
CreatePalette[
 Column[
  {
   Button[
    "Align at 10%",
    FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[],
     "TextAlignment", -0.8]
    ],
   Button[
    "Align at 25%",
    FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[],
     "TextAlignment", -0.5]
    ]
   }
  ],
 WindowTitle -> "Align Cells"
 ]
```

Now select a cell and click the appropriate button and the text is aligned.

Note the -0.8 value to align text at 10%.

It is OK to explicitly use the tokens Left, Center and Right. One gets the same result if -1 is used for Left, 0 for Center and 1 for Right.