# How to create a Palette to Edit TaggingRules for a Cell?

Tags: front-end, user-interface, palettes

I am trying to find a way to append to the TaggingRules for a currently selected cell.  This idea is similar to Cell->Cell Tags->Add/Remove Cell Tags, but with fields for a specific set of TaggingRule options.

I've been looking a various posts and documentation--I am overwhelmed with information and not sure where to start. I am hoping someone might suggest a good place to start.  Some promising places that I've found are: [Documentation Tools by  b3m2a1](https://b3m2a1.github.io/simplifying-mathematica-documentation.html#main-content), [stackexchange post on changing Cell options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42237/palette-to-set-cell-options-such-as-background-editable-and-initialization-prope), [Joy of Tagging](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7246/), and [Tracking Palette States](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StoringAndTrackingPaletteStates.html).

My purpose is that I have several co-authors on a set of notebooks. I'd like them to add to TaggingRules in a structured way. For example, the currently selected cell might have

```
TaggingRules->{"keywords"->{"apples", "fruit"},"anchor"->{"section:food"},"bibtexKey"->"AppleSeedJ:1794"}
```

I'd like to create a ButtonNotebook or a Palette (or anything of this genre), that has something akin to (*making up code to signal my intent, not working code*):

```
Grid[
{
{"Current Key Words", CurrentValue[InputNotebook[],(*???*)]},
{"New Key Word",InputField[Dynamic[newKeyword]]},
{"Location",InputField[Dynamic[anchor]]}
}
]
```

which would:

1. Create empty TaggingRules for the selected Cell if that option not set
2. Find and Dynamically display specific TaggingRules options if it exists
3. Append the contents of the InputField to the TaggingRules option.

Just a nudge in the right direction will be appreciated.