# Selection of all the objects with the same style in a notebook

Tags: front-end

In a notebook, I would like to select all the cells with the "Text" style to change their style.

How is possible to do this with a automatic process?

For the moment I can do it only cell by cell.

Comment: This answer changes Section to Title so that's basically the same: [Set the style of a cell](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78774/5478)

Comment: You can alt-click a text cell and all of them will be selected.

Comment: alt-click is Perfect ! Thank you